# Deciding on a charset for email

Tags: c#, encoding, email-validation

I'm currently encoding my emails as `1252`, but wondered if this was the correct encoding to use.  Should I be using `UTF8`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I recommend UTF8, is more internet-wide and multi-lang

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target languages. if your e-mails are English only, `1252` is ok. But if you want to use different langauges, `UTF8` is the proper solution.

Comment: It's also useful for funny images: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 0):

If you control 100% of the content of the email, then you don't really need to worry about this (1252 is fine).

If you have any aspect of dynamic content that may be populated by a user then you will want to provided broader support and to that end UTF8 is a better choice.